# Calculating days in month in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone help me with my python code?

I am learning python and I have an error I can't fix and I can't understand what's wrong.

So can anyone help me to fix it and tell me why it's wrong?

```
def leap_year(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    elif year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    elif year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def days_in_month(month):
    if month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 \
    or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
        return month == 31
    elif month == 2:
        if leap_year(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    else:
        return 30
```

Comment: What exactly is your question / issue? Please provide some sample input and sample output. Describe what you are expecting and what the actual situation is.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of bugs in your code:

- `days_in_month` is a function of both `month` and `year`. Define it accordingly.
- Returning `month == 31` has no meaning. Your output should be a number of days, not a Boolean.

In addition, I've simplified your code to decrease the number of `or` / `if` / `elif` / `else` statements.

```
def leap_year(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def days_in_month(month, year):
    if month in {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}:
        return 31
    if month == 2:
        if leap_year(year):
            return 29
        return 28
    return 30

print(days_in_month(2, 2016))  # 29
```

Comment: Leap years are not that simple, OP has the right idea there.

Comment: @AlexHall, I've merely replicated OP's *intended* logic, which contained errors. I'm not making a statement on the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: No, you've changed the logic. 2100 is not a leap year, for example. OP's function gets that right, yours doesn't.

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't really need `elif` (just `if`) or `else` clauses because each clause returns.

Comment: it didn't work my error is that
if leap_year(year):
NameError: global name 'year' is not defined
and i don't know why?

Comment: @OmarBaz, Start a new Python session. Copy-paste my code exactly. Evidence it works: https://repl.it/repls/HastyPrevailingSecurity